# Como proteger meus videos

Tags: php

Desculpa minha falta de conhecimento, mas não sei ao certo por onde começar a pesquisar. O problema é que eu uso jwplayer para reproduzir meus vídeos, eu hospedo eles no meu próprio servidor e gostaria de criar um link temporário, semelhante o que o youtube, vimeo e todos o sites de vídeos, de preferência uma solução em php

Exemplo:

```
Meu codigo
<video>
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

Como eu gostaria
<video>
  <source src="http://video.site.com/55848/85778.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Não precisa ser exatamente assim, mas uma solução para proteger meus vídeos de serem usados por outros, e assim não consumir recursos do meu servidor.

Comment: O primeiro passo é não apontar o URL para o caminho real do vídeo. Qual é o servidor http usado?

Comment: O servidor é Apache

Comment: O apache tem um módulo chamado x-sendfile, muito útil para esses casos. Se você apontar o URL para um PHP que valide um cookie, e usar um `header("X-Sendfile: /caminho/correto/paraovideo.mp4");`, a pessoa recebe os dados sem saber o caminho original. Dá pra fazer sem esse módulo, mas aí o stream inteiro tem que passar pelo processamento do PHP, o que nem sempre é desejável. Outra vantagem do x-sendfile é que suporta _ranges_, o que é desejável para stream de vídeos.

Comment: Ok muito obrigada, vou estudar o x-sendfile. Você poderia colocar como resposta esse comentário?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como você disse que usa Apache, tem uma ferramenta bem interessante para enviar arquivos sob controle do PHP, mas ao mesmo tempo sem precisar do PHP para gerar a comunicação, que é o módulo `x-sendfile`.

> http://blog.jasny.net/articles/how-i-php-x-sendfile/

Este módulo permite que você devolva o controle da conexão ao Apache, indicando um arquivo para ser servido, e para isto, basta setar um *header*:

```
X-Sendfile: /caminho
```

Suponho que você já tenha alguma maneira de autenticar o usuário. Supondo que ele esteja autorizado a ver os vídeos, uma possibilidade é gravar um token em uma sessão, e validar desta forma:

listavideos.php

```
<?php
    // estou supondo que você autenticou o usuário,
    // e criou um token único, aleatório e complexo
    // para ele em $_SESSION['token']

    session_start();

    ...

    echo '<source src="/show.php?token='.$_SESSION['token'].'&video=23" type="video/mp4">';
```

E no show.php:

```
session_start();

if( $_GET['token'] == $_SESSION['token'] ) {
    header( 'Content-type: video/mp4' );
    // aqui vai o caminho real para o vídeo, que não aparecerá para
    // o usuário final. Sugiro fazer um sistema mais complexo que
    // este do exemplo, usar um hash para o nome real do video, 
    // ou mesmo colocar os vídeos num lugar inacessível para uso
    // "direto".
    header( 'X-Sendfile: /videos/caminhocomplexo/'.$video.'.mp4' );
    die();
} else {
    echo 'Link inválido';
    die();
}
```

Claro que eu simplifiquei o código para ilustrar, mas a idéia básica é essa. Obviamente que depois você pode caprichar mais fazendo o URL amigável (por exemplo, passando os dados no caminho do URL e não na *query string*, mas aí já é "melhoria").

### Mandando sem X-Sendfile

Usando a mesma lógica de cima, podemos trocar o *header* `X-Sendfile` por isso:

```
readfile( '/videos/caminhocomplexo/'.$video.'.mp4' );
```

Só que precisa ter em mente que isso faz com que durante o envio todo dos dados, o processo do PHP estará em execução, e isso pode ocasionar um `timeout` em boa parte das hospedagens.

Adicionalmente, se for um *stream* longo, precisaria dar um suporte a *ranges*, ou seja, permitir que algum cliente comece a ler os dados do meio do vídeo, por exemplo.

O PHP permite setar o tempo de execução  de um script, mas ele não pode passar nunca do máximo definido no `PHP.ini`, que muitas vezes não é acessível pelo cliente da hospedagem.

Comment: a sim, por um instante pensei que estava verificando a sessão e seria alguma coisa com o X-Senfile, mas não tinha entendido, blz então. +1 pelo X-SendFile