# Como posso restringir download de arquivos através de autenticação em PHP?

Tags: php, autenticação, download

Tenho um sistema onde o usuário pode enviar fazer upload de áudios. O nível de usuário que pode fazer isso é o cliente. Porém, do outro lado, eu tenho as pessoas que podem fazer o download desses arquivos para efetuar a transcrição do áudio. Apenas pessoas autenticadas (e com seus respectivos níveis) podem ter acesso a esses arquivos.

O problema é que geralmente fazemos o upload de arquivos para uma pasta pública, onde é possível acessar o link para download. Porém, nesse caso, não quero que isso aconteça, pois alguém que perdesse o acesso ao sistema poderia ter acesso a esse link caso uma outra pessoa passasse.

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de restringir acesso à downloads de arquivos por autenticação.

Preciso apenas de uma ideia para saber como posso fazer de uma maneira que somente quem esteja autenticado tenha acesso aos downloads.

**Observação**: A resposta nem precisa ter código, mas apenas ideias de como eu fazer.

Comment: Tá usando algum framework? Acabei de passar por isso e estava usando laravel. A lógica básica é remover do public (claro) e fazer uma "stream" do arquivo numa rota autenticada.

Comment: @RafaelMenaBarreto boa ideia. Se quiser pode adicionar isso como resposta. E sim, eu uso Laravel. Se tiver alguma forma de adicionar uma resposta para quem usa "PHP puro", ficará melhor ainda

Comment: Ok estou criando uma resposta

Comment: Duplicata dessa anterior? ;) http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/128049/70

Comment: Parece que sim.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pode tentar o meio simples onde o PHP lê o arquivo inteiro e despacha para o usuário. Contudo, essa técnica tem um custo alto pois consome memória, e quanto maior o arquivo, maior será o consumo.

Podemos considerar grande os arquivos a partir de 1mb. E isso é proporcional ao volume de acessos. Num site muito movimentado por exemplo, 10kb é também pesado. Enfim.

Uma opção viável é usar em conjunto com o módulo [X-SendFile](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/).

Caso consiga instalar o X-SendFile no servidor, é uma melhor opção em relação ao uso de funções como `file_get_contents()`, `readfile()` e `fopen()`.

A lógica no uso do X-SendFile é que é feito um "desvio de rota" durante o processamento do PHP onde o próprio servidor web (apache, nginx, etc) fará o despacho desse arquivo para o usuário, sem precisar usar o PHP para ler o arquivo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na imagem acima, o processo tradicional usando somente o PHP.

**①** Usuário requisita

**②** Webserver envia dados para o PHP

**③** PHP processa (faz autentição e qualquer outra coisa)
Então faz leitura do aquivo.

**④** O PHP escreve o conteúdo do arquivo para o webserver

**⑤** O webserver despacha para o usuário

Veja a mesma situação com X-SendFile

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**①** Usuário requisita

**②** Webserver envia dados para o PHP

**③** PHP processa (faz autentição e qualquer outra coisa)
Então despacha um header para o webserver (o trabalho do PHP termina aqui).

**④** O webserver entende o header e invoca o módulo X-SendFile que devolve o caminho do arquivo que deve ser despachado.

<sub>Nota: O X-SendFile não faz leitura do conteúdo do arquivo. Apenas informa ao webserver que o conteúdo a ser despachado está no caminho especificado no header fornecido pelo PHP.</sub>

## Exemplo prático

Não é um exemplo completo de download autenticado conforme pede a pergunta, porém, é um exemplo útil para entender como usar o X-SendFile.

Crie uma pasta no seu localhost ou seja lá onde preferir:

```
/xsendfile
```

Dentro dessa pasta crie uma pasta `imgx` e um arquivo `index.html` com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
ok, imagem<br>
<img src="img/1.jpg">
```

Lembre-se que anteriormente criamos a pasta `imgx` mas no HTML estamos chamando `img/` que não existe.

A estrutura está assim

```
/xsendfile
    /index.html
    /imgx/1.jpg
```

O arquivo `1.jpg` é uma imagem qualquer para teste. Deve estar dentro da pasta `imgx`. Essa pasta será acessível pelo X-SendFile.

Crie um arquivo `.htaccess` com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
XSendFile on

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?img/(.*)$ /xsendfile/img.php?file=$1 [L,R=301]
```

Salve-o na pasta `/xsendfile`

Agora a estrutura está assim:

```
/xsendfile
    /.htaccess
    /index.html
    /imgx/1.jpg
```

Vamos criar o roteador. No htaccess é `img.php`.

Esse é o código:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');

ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED); // & ~E_NOTICE
ini_set('log_errors', true);
ini_set('html_errors', false);
ini_set('display_errors', true);

/*
The images must be on the same directory or into subfolders.
Not allowed to load images from up folders.

Must turn it on into htaccess file:
    XSendFile on
*/

/*
true: send file headers
false: do not send the file headers
*/
define('FILE_HEADERS_ENABLED', false);

if (isset($_GET['file'])) {
    $file = $_GET['file'];
}

// File's absolute path
/*
Lembra da pasta "imgx"? É aqui que setamos o caminho real. 
Lembre-se que o nome da pasta deve ser dificil de ser advinhada caso esteja num diretório público. Mais para frente explico porque nesse exemplo colocamos numa pasta pública.
*/
$path = __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'imgx'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file;

// Checking if path exists.
// Se o arquivo não existir, carregará uma imagem padrão.
if (!file_exists($path)) {
    // Path not found. Will load default missing image.
    $path = __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'imgx'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'no_image.gif';    
}


/* 
Aqui ou em qualquer outra parte que for conveniente para o seu caso,
poderia chamar rotinas de autenticação, por exemplo.
*/
$autentica_algo = true;
if ($autentica_algo === false) {
    // aqui não autenticou, então interrompe, envia um arquivo falso ou sei lá.. Cada um inventa a firula que quiser.
}


/*
Os headers abaixo pode apagar se quiser. Não faz diferença. Mas dependendo do caso pode ser útil.
Normalmente utilizo para testes.
*/
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); //HTTP 1.1
header("Pragma: no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past

if (FILE_HEADERS_ENABLED) {
    $info = getimagesize($path);
    header('Content-type: '.$info['mime']);
    header('Content-length: '.filesize($path));
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
}

// Sent the x-sendfile header
// Esse header invoca o módulo X-Sendfile.
header('X-Sendfile: '.$path);

/*
Aqui pode usar um exit se preferir que o script não continue. Mas normalmente já interrompe no header acima.
Por via das dúvidas, interrompa explicitamente.
*/
exit;
```

Com isso tudo temos a estrutura:

```
/xsendfile
    /.htaccess
    /index.html
    /img.php
    /imgx/1.jpg
```

Execute e veja o que acontece: `http://localhost/xsendfile/`

Será exibido a imagem que está na pasta `imgx` mesmo não existindo o local `img/1.jpg`.

Experimente remover ou desabilitar o .htaccess e veja o que acontece. Retorna um not found na imagem pois não há um roteamento e portanto não carregará a imagem invocada pelo X-SendFile.

Também pode tentar diretamente no browser `http://localhost/xsendfile/img/1.jpg` pois o htaccess toma conta do redirect e o `img.php` invocará o X-SendFile.

## Como instalar o X-SendFile?

Para usar o X-Sendfile normalmente necessita de acesso administrativo ao servidor (dedicado, vps). Geralmente em hospedagem compartilhada não existe o módulo instalado e dificilmente o suporte do provedor faria a instalação. Portanto essa solução é normalmente mais acessível para quem tem acesso administrativo ao ambiente do servidor.

*Considerando o Apache como webserver

Para Windows: https://www.apachelounge.com/download/ ou https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/

Para Linux: https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/

## Explicação adicional sobre a estrutura do exemplo

Para entender melhor, seguindo o exemplo acima:

```
/xsendfile
    /.htaccess
    /index.html
    /img.php
    /imgx/1.jpg
```

Para proteger ainda mais os arquivos da pasta `imgx/`, poderíamos colocá-la fora da pasta pública.

```
c:/ww/private/imgx/1.jpg
c:/ww/public/xsendfile
    /.htaccess
    /index.html
    /img.php
```

Isso seria o ideal, mas o X-SendFile não permite recuo de diretórios por razões de segurança. É possível aplicar dessa forma fazendo algumas implementações mas, para evitar complicar o exemplo, demonstrei de uma forma mais simples.

O módulo é open source e qualquer pessoa pode recompilar e remover tais restrições. Mas só faça isso se souber o que está fazendo.

## Observações no uso do X-SendFile

1. Normalmente entra em conflito com regras de reescrita de URL.
   Caso tenha regras de reescrita num sistema já em funcionamento, prefira usar o X-SendFile separado desse sistema. A menos que você seja um mazoquista e queira fazer gambiaras para tornar compatível.
2. Não é possível enviar para o cabeçalho X-SendFile, arquivos acima do diretório de onde é invocado. Ou seja, não é permitido definir um path com recuo de diretórios.
3. O módulo é desenvolvido por um terceiro sem suporte de uma empresa que garanta continuidade. Esse é talvez o ponto mais fraco pois o dia que o desenvolvedor deixar de manter, todos que usam ficarão sem updates e suporte ou terão que aprender a ler o código e dar continudade ao projeto. Enfim, isso depende da comunidade de developers.

Comment: Daniel, essa daí eu não conhecia. Surpreendente. Vou dar uma pesquisadinha aqui :D

Comment: Mas no caso de usar `readfile` ao invés de usar `file_get_contents` não seria mais "econômico"?

Comment: também dá na mesma.. file_get_contents, readfile, fopen, etc.. mesmo com uso de técnicas de stream.. o problema é que está lendo o arquivo inteiro para então escrevê-lo e tudo isso dentro do servidor.. que no final despacha para o usuário. O ideal é o servidor despachar diretamente ser precisar ler nada.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters de jeito nenhum, fazer com file_ é muito mais "pesado". X-Sendfile devolve pro servidor de páginas o controle, e escapa de todo o buffer do PHP. É uma camada a menos, e ainda economiza o controle "manual" de cache, pois tirando o caminho, o servidor de páginas faz praticamente como se fosse um arquivo estático. No Apache é um módulo separado.

Comment: @Bacco você tá vivo, né! Vou dar uma olhada nessa "parada" agora :D

Comment: @WallaceMaxters eu acabo de usar para um sistema de thumbnails. O PHP gera a imagem se não existir miniatura, e salva na pasta. Mas o X-Sendfile é quem serve ela da pasta de cache. https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/ (e tá dado o +1 pro Omine pela resposta)

Comment: rsrs.. estou com muito sono.. mas vou fazer uma forcinha para colocar mais coisas.. falta pouco..

Comment: +1 não conhecia essa maneira e muito menos esse módulo (:

Comment: Talvez, para facilitar para usuarios do SO que vierem depois consultar esse tópico, seja bom informar no inicio da resposta que essa alternativa necessita de acesso administrativo as configurações do servidor. E não apenas aos arquivos do projeto, como indicado nas tags da pergunta. Pois muitos usuários com hospedagem compartilhada não poderão utilizar essa opção mesmo podendo ser mais eficiente.

Comment: com base no texto acima "um custo alto pois consome memória" qual seria o custo alto? Estou com um sistema de download e pelos testes tenho percebido que ao efetuar o download de uma arquivo sem outro não tenha terminado destrói a sessão do download. Isso poderia ser um dos preços do consumo de memória da forma tradicional?

Comment: Não posso dizer qual o motivo do seu problema específico, @adrianosymphony. Pode ser um caso de abrir uma pergunta.

Comment: @DanielOmine grato pela reposta. Já a pergunta já está aberta em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/157096/fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-readfile-derrubando-sess%C3%A3o-php

Answer (score 5):

Primeiramente, o arquivo para download não poderia estar disponível publicamente.

Depois você precisaria criar uma rota lógica para o diretório de arquivos para download. Como exemplo, vou utilizar `/downloads/[arquivo]`.

No seu serviço http (apache, nginx), você precisaria definir o redirect para essa rota.

---

Exemplo para Apache:

`RewriteRule "^/downloads/.*$"  "downloads.php"`

Sendo `downloads.php` seu script que validará a autenticação do usuário.

---

No arquivo `downloads.php` você precisaria verificar se o usuário está autenticado, e redireciona-lo para a página de login em caso negativo, ou enviar o arquivo caso ja esteja autenticado.

---

Exemplo:

```
// Verifica autenticação
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    header('location: /login.php');
    exit;
}

// Usuário autenticado

// Caminho do arquivo, assumindo que o diretório de download está em ../downloads
$path = '../' . parse_url($_SERVER['request_uri', PHP_URL_PATH);

if (!file_exists($path)) {
    // Arquivo não existe
    http_response_code(404);
    exit;
}


// Não foquei em pegar o file_mime e o file_name para encurtar a resposta e pois foge do escopo da resposta.
header('Content-Type: ' . $file_mime); 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $file_name . '"');
readfile($path);
```

Comment: Muito bom, jovem. Parabéns pela resposta. Mereceu +1

Answer (score 2):

A lógica por trás desta restrição consiste nestes passos:

- Remover os itens do diretório público
- Criar uma rota que receba o arquivo como parâmetro
- Na rota autenticada abrimos o arquivo e iniciamos uma stream do mesmo

Em PHP puro o usuário acessaria um endereço (exemplo: 'http//www.meusite.com.br/arquivos.php?nome=file1.jpg')
Esta rota faria a verificação normal se o usuário está autenticado ou não e retornaria a imagem diretamente pra ele. Exemplo usando uma imagem:

```
$file = fopen('localdoarquivo');
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $file;
```

Este exemplo é o mais "a marretada possível" note que u forcei o tipo da imagem para jpeg.

Usando um framework como o Laravel tudo fica mais simplificado, dá pra usar o storage pra buscar o arquivo e o intervention pra retornar a imagem independentemente da extensão:

```
try {
       $image = Storage::disk('seu-storage')->get($filename);
        } catch (\Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\FileNotFoundException $fl) {
            $response = new Response();
            $response->setStatusCode(404);
            $response->setContent(['success' => false, 'msg' => 'Arquivo não encontrado']);
            return $response;
        }

        return Image::make($image)->response();
```

Como a pergunta fala em áudio  mudamos o return ali para:

```
    $response = new Response($audio);

    return $response;
```

Que o arquivo (independente da extensão) será enviado ao computador do usuário como um download.

Comment: É isso mesmo. A do Laravel ajuda muito. Quem ainda gosta de usar o PHP puro ainda tem a primeira opção.  +1